# How to detect constraints causing infeasibility in MIP in CPLEX (OPL IDE)

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a set of constraints that make my solution infeasible in CPLEX (coded in OPL IDE). How to figure out which constraints are causing infeasibility?

Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

```
  0     0    infeasible                                      11429
```

- Trying to calibrate parameters to actual values reported. 
  --- 2 parameters unknown. Trying to set constraints to match model output on some decision variables close to their actual values. The constraints may be too tight. I tried making them flexible by allowing a range of acceptable values on the RHS.

--

No solution is the error message

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the conflicts on the [Conflict](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/gsoplide/topics/opl_ide_gs_tut_output_tabs.html#gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1044796__gsoplide.uss_ide_gettingstarted.1044870) tab. For example, here is a screenshot from the documentation:

[image]

You can read more about this in the tutorial on [relaxing infeasible models](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplide/topics/opl_ide_relax.html) and also [diagnosing infeasibility by refining conflicts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/infeas_unbd/conflict_refiner/01_ref_confl_title_synopsis.html) in the CPLEX User's Manual.

TIP: Make sure you have [labeled your constraints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_constraints_labels.html).